# What is difference in checking eof() on getline i.e. while(!getline().eof()) and checking simply while(getline())

Tags: c++, delimiter, eof, getline

What is difference between while(getline()) & while(!getline().eof()) ?

Am parsing an input string.
I have tried with both condition check and I see the difference in result.

```
std::string testStr = "CN=Test, OU=XYZ, O=ABC";
std::stringstream inpStrStream(testStr);
std::string tempStr;
getline(inpStrStream, tempStr, '=');
std::cout<<"Hello:"<<tempStr<<std::endl;

//Let's call this as "Ex A"
while(getline(inpStrStream, tempStr, '='))
{
   std::cout<<tempStr<<std::endl;
}
    (OR)
//Let's call this as "Ex B"
while(!getline(inpStrStream, tempStr, '=').eof())
{
   std::cout<<tempStr<<std::endl;
}
```

I expected same result in both but the result for "Ex A" & "Ex B" are different. I don't see string "ABC" in output of "Ex B":

Ex A result:
Hello:CN
Test, OU
XYZ, O
ABC

Ex B result:
Hello:CN
Test, OU
XYZ, O

Comment: one check for all errors, the other one for specific error: try read beyond file size.

Comment: The "Ex B" exits the loop after successfully parsing `ABC` to the `tempStr`, but because EOF is tripped, doesn't print that last parse results.

Answer (score 1):

Ref.: [CppReference.com, "iostate"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate)

`getline()` returns a reference of the stream it is operating on, i.e. `inpStrStream`.

`inpStrStream.operator bool()` (or `while ( inpStrStream )` / `while ( getline( inpStrStream, tempStr, '=' ) )` ) will check if `failbit` or `badbit` of the stream are set.

`! inpStrStream.eof()` will check if `eofbit` of the stream is set. (*)

CppReference states,

> ...in nearly all situations, if `eofbit` is set, `failbit` is set as well.

You've hit one of the exceptions here. `.operator!()` checks for `failbit`, **not** for `eofbit` -- ant that `getline()` of `"ABC"` does set `eofbit` (as EOF of the stream is reached), *but not `failbit`* (as that last operation was still successful). This makes `.eof()` end the loop (not printing `"ABC"`), while `.operator!()` will do one more iteration (printing `"ABC"`), trying another `getline()`, which fails (as there is nothing more to read), setting `failbit`, and ending the loop.

So... `.eof()` will *explicitly* test for EOF *only*, i.e. will try to continue even if something nasty has happened to the underlying stream that did get one of the other two flags set.

---

(*): Note that there are more tests. The only symmetric ones are `.fail()` and `.operator!()` (which test the same thing), and their symmetric opposite `.operator bool()`. The others -- `.good()`, `.bad()`, and `.eof()` -- check different things each!

Comment: "while .operator!() will do one more iteration (printing "ABC") "- This statement is confusing as for Ex B case we don't see ABC printed.

Comment: @Pravinkumar: We do not see ABC printed in Ex. B because that's not `inpStrStream.operator!()` (as in Ex. A), but the negation of `inpStrStream.eof()`.

Comment: So what i understand is getline()  checks for  failbit or badbit of stream are set and since its not set so it prints ABC whereas getline().eof checks for eof encountered and since it encounters eof so it returns true & hence !true is false and hence the while condition exits ??

Comment: @Pravinkumar: Sorry, it wasn't `operator!()`, it was `operator bool()`. My bad. Same reasoning, though.

Comment: @Pravinkumar: Not `getline()` is checking. `getline()` returns a reference to a stream. `while ()` expects a boolean. Evaluating a stream reference as boolean invokes `.operator bool()` on that stream. That will be true if `! failbit && ! badbit`. In contrast to that, `! (/*stream*/).eof()` will be true if `! eofbit`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on this simple test code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

#define LOG(x) std::cout << __LINE__ << ": " #x " = " << x << '\n'

void test(char termChar)
{

    std::stringstream input;
    input << "lets try this!";
    std::string s;
    std::getline(input, s, termChar);
    
    LOG(!!input);
    LOG(input.eof());
    LOG(input.tellg());
    char ch = '?';
    
    input >> ch;
    LOG(!!input);
    LOG(input.eof());
    LOG(input.tellg());
    LOG(ch);
}

int main()
{
    test('!');
    std::cout << '\n';
    test('#');
    
    return 0;
}
```

And its output: https://godbolt.org/z/f55eTjWK1

```
14: !!input = 1
15: input.eof() = 0
16: input.tellg() = 14
20: !!input = 0
21: input.eof() = 1
22: input.tellg() = -1
23: ch = ?

14: !!input = 1
15: input.eof() = 1
16: input.tellg() = -1
20: !!input = 0
21: input.eof() = 1
22: input.tellg() = -1
23: ch = ?
```

1. Remember `eof` doesn't mean that you are at the end of stream, but that you have tried to read stream beyond its size.
2. Now in second run of `test` `getline` was successful (`!!input`) but there was attempt to read beyond stream size so `eof` returns `true`. Now your loop with `eof` can reject things which are important for you since `eof` is set to `true` but reading was a success.

Answer (score 0):

The class `std::stringstream` inherits the class `std::basic_ios` that defines the operator

```
explicit operator bool() const;
```

that

> 1 Returns: !fail().

This operator is used in the condition of the while statement

```
while(getline(inpStrStream, tempStr, '='))
```

to contextually convert the object returned by the call of `std::getline`  to the type bool.

From the C++ Standard (C++ 17, 7 Standard conversions)

> 4 Certain language constructs require that an expression be converted
>   to a Boolean value. An expression e appearing in such a context is
>   said to be contextually converted to bool and is well-formed if and
>   only if the declaration bool t(e); is well-formed, for some invented
>   temporary variable t (11.6).